# Java - start thread with member function

Tags: java, multithreading

I have one class that extends "Thread" class. This child class is already implementing the run() method. But is it possible to create another user defined method(say saveData(Object obj)) in the same child class and instead of calling the start() method, call saveData() to create a new thread and execute the instructions inside the method saveData().

And what would happen if I create an object of the child class and call saveData() on that object.?

Comment: Unless you call start method, the actual thread will never come into existence and if you call saveData method on object, it will just be a normal call in your currently running thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `java.lang.Thread` class is not essentially different from any other Java class. It has methods, and when you call them, they do what they do.

A `java.lang.Thread` is not a *thread*, in exactly the same way that a `java.awt.Window` instance is not a *window*.  Threads and windows belong to the operating system, and the corresponding Java objects are the "handles" that you use to interface with the operating system.  The `Thread` method that creates a new operating system thread is called `t.start()`.

Suppose you define a class that extends `Thread`

```
class MyThread extends Thread {
    ...
    public void saveData(...) { ... }
    ...
}
```

> what would happen if I create an object of the child class and call saveData() on that object.?

You're asking us? But *you* are the person who wrote the method!! When your program calls `my_thread.saveData(...)`, it'll be like calling any other method that you wrote in any other class that you defined.  You are the one who wrote the method. It'll do whatever you put inside those curly braces.

---

The only thing that's even slightly magic about the `Thread` class is the `start()` method.  If you write this:

```
class MyClass extends Thread {
    ...
    public void saveData(...) { ... }
    public void run() { ... }
    ...
}
```

Then when your program calls `new MyThread().start()`, the start method will "magically" create a new thread, and the new thread will call the `run()` method...

...which you also wrote, and which will do whatever you put inside *its* curly braces.

If you want `saveData()` to be called in the new thread, then make sure that it gets called from somewhere within the `run()` method.